# How to add feature class to MXD with ArcPy (Python)?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, layers, mxd

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 and I am trying to add a feature class that I create to an MXD, so that I can join to it.

This all needs to be done using Python.

Is this possible?

Comment: When i run this script i see the layer pop up in the layers by drawing orger content but once the script completes it disapears... ??

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Before you can add a feature class you need to turn it into a feature layer.

This arcpy code should help:

```
import arcpy

FC = r"C:\...\featureclass"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FC, "nameoffeatureclass")

MXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\...\your.mxd")
DF = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(MXD)[0]

layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("nameoffeatureclass")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(DF, layer, "AUTO_ARRANGE")

MXD.save()

del MXD
```

Edit: the above code adds the layer to the first dataframe (index 0) - keep this in mind if you have multiple.

Comment: It's actually not necessary to create a feature layer first. Skip `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FC, "nameoffeatureclass")`. If you leave it in you actually have two layers at the end of your code instead of one.