# Adding all feature classes of same name to mxd in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, feature-class

I have a bunch of folders which all have (almost) identical folder structures and file geodatabases of identical structures which in this folder structure. I need to add all of the same type of feature class to an mxd and merge them into a new feature class. There are a lot of them so I thought this seemed like the sort of thing I could do in python.

The folders are all in the same folder and there is a common path to the feature class in question, for example:

```
project_name/Subfolder1/subfolder2/project_name.gdb/featuredataset/featureclass.
```

so I'm thinking of trying to loop through the folders and extraxt the feature class from each of them using a method like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/62897/17646), but I'm not quite sure how arcpy interacts with, and loops through windows folders.

Since I'm looking for any feature class of this name within the root folder could I use a more brute force method that searches in the root folder and subfolders for the name and adds it to the mxd?

Comment: It seems that adding the FC's to a .mxd is an unnecessary step.  Could this step be eliminated if all of the files were located and merged directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Something a little more robust than my notepad outline:

Method one: List the directories in the root folder and slap the suffix on the end.

Method two: Use os.walk to go through the folders

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace ="in_memory"
project = "c:\\Users\\roo\\Desktop\\project_name"
suffix = "test.gdb\\test_verts"

# setup mxd and map document
MAP = project + "\\Untitled.mxd"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MAP)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]

# method one
for folder in os.listdir(project):
    if os.path.isdir(folder):
        fc = os.path.join(project, folder, suffix)
        if arcpy.Exists(fc):
            lyr = os.path.basename(fc) + "_" + folder
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, lyr)
            addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(lyr)
            arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "BOTTOM")
mxd.save()

# method two
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(project):
    for dirs in dirnames:
        fc = os.path.join(project, dirs, suffix)
        if arcpy.Exists(fc):
            lyr = os.path.basename(fc) + "_" + dirs
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, lyr)
            addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(lyr)
            arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "BOTTOM")
mxd.save()
```

Comment: If @whatahitson were using ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 or later then [**arcpy.da.Walk**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000023000000) would be useful here.

Comment: You should wrap your layer creation and adding the layer to the mxd with a try...except block, just in case you encounter a corrupt dataset.