# Using ArcPy: adding feature class and fields in an un-saved mxd

Tags: arcpy, feature-class

With ArcPy I have created a tool that creates an empty feature class with pre-defined fields and adds it to the TOC.  It works quite well, however if I use the tool to generate a feature class in an unsaved MXD it hangs.  I can get around it by naming and saving the MXD (it'S a bit cumbersome).
I'd like to change the code so that I can add a feature class to the TOC without necessarily creating an MXD project each time.

```
#------------------------------------------------------
# currently only works on a saved mxd.  needs to be able to add to an unsaved docuement.
#----------------------------------------------------------------
import arcpy
#import time feature - to insert date into field, but not functional yet.
from time import strftime
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "CURRENT"

#--------------DEFINE VARIABLES---------------
in_wrkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
projectNumber = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
FeatureDescription = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
in_GeomType = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
spatialRefCode = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)


#-----------------DEFINE EXPRESSIONS-----------------
FeatureClass = '_'+ str(projectNumber) + '_cm_' + str(FeatureDescription) + '_' + strftime("%y%m%d")


#Create feature class within workspace and add fields
FC = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(in_wrkspace,FeatureClass,in_GeomType,"","DISABLED","DISABLED",spatialRefCode)
for FeatureClass in FC:

    # Process: classe
    arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "classe", "TEXT", "", "", "50", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

    # Process: objet
    arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "objet", "TEXT", "", "", "200", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    #Process: source
    arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "source", "TEXT", "", "", "80", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    #Process: date
    arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "date", "TEXT", "", "", "10", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    #Process: remarque
    arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "remarque", "TEXT", "", "", "250", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    #Process: traitment
    arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "traitment", "TEXT", "", "", "250", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    #Process: no_seq
    arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass,"NO_SEQ", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    #make feature layer

#Create a layer file to add to MXD
temp = '_'+ str(projectNumber) + '_cm_' + str(FeatureDescription) + '_' + strftime("%y%m%d")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FeatureClass,temp)



#-----------------add the layer to data frame--------------------------
#source: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62896/how-to-add-feature-class-to-mxd-with-arcpy-python
#arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("in_memory",FeatureClass)
MXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
DF = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(MXD)[0]
Layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(temp)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(DF,Layer,"AUTO_ARRANGE")
MXD.save()
#delete in memory cache layer



del MXD #, DF, Layer
arcpy.Delete_management(Layer)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you Hornbydd and GISGe.  Both of your answers worked perfectly well.  I opted for Hornbydd's solution although either one would have been excellent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran your code, works fine for me. I did make the following changes:

1. After the line where you set the workspace I added the line:

   env.addOutputsToMap = False
2. I delete the *MakeFeatureLayer* line
3. Edited what temp was set to so changed line to

   temp = FeatureClass

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

What if you just remove `MXD.save()` and add `arcpy.RefreshTOC()` to make sure the added layer is visible?