# Adding feature class into ArcGIS 10.3 mxd using python script

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, arcgis-10.3, feature-class

I am trying this simple task to add a feature class to an mxd (ArcGIS 10.3) but getting few errors. Here are two options I tried.

1) Preferred option - adding feature class itself into a active dataframe of the current
mxd. I used the script below:

```
import arcpy

mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

DF=mxd.activeDataFrame

arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(DF,"C:\Work\GP1500\Tests\Input.gdb\Poly1","TOP")
```

The addLayer line generates the error below
...... 
assert isinstance(add_layer, Layer)
AssertionError

2) Create a layer from the Feature class and add the layer using the script *****

```
import arcpy

mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

DF=mxd.activeDataFrame

FC="C:\Test.gdb\Test_Poly1"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FC,"TestPolyLayer")

inputlayer =arcpy.mapping.layer(TestPolyLayer)

arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(DF,inputlayer,"TOP")
```

******It generates the error while executing the second last line i.e. to define input layer with following message
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'layer'

Note: the second option i used is after I saw Nick's reply in [How to add feature class to MXD with ArcPy (Python)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62896/how-to-add-feature-class-to-mxd-with-arcpy-python)

Answer (score 3):

You need to first create the [Layer object](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/), and then use [AddLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000025000000) to add it:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

df = mxd.activeDataFrame

layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("C:\Work\GP1500\Tests\Input.gdb\Poly1")

arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer, "TOP")
```